# How can mounting a VeraCrypt drive be done without root in Linux?

Tags: linux, mount, truecrypt, removable-media, veracrypt

I used TrueCrypt for a long time in Kubuntu, in which I used a keyboard shortcut to automatically mount a drive. Nowadays I use VeraCrypt, but I am always prompted for my sudo password after entering the password for the encrypted drive. This was never necessary in TrueCrypt.

It occurred to me that I could potentially mount the drive as a removable media (this is an operation that does not require a root password), but when mounting the drive to /mount/ (which is where removable media is mounted), I *still* get the sudo password request.

Furthermore, an option in VeraCrypt allows [Volume Mounted as Removable Medium](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Removable%20Medium%20Volume), but this option simply doesn't exist in the version I'm running in Linux (v1.19).

What is going on here? How can I request that the VeraCrypt mounting process behave like removable media? Entering my password every mount and dismount is irritating.

Comment: Non-system volumes can be mounted during the session without password by selecting Settings > 'System Encryption' and enabling 'Cache pre-boot authentication password in driver memory'. Does this help?

Comment: In VeraCrypt? I don't have that option. I _do_ feel like features are missing in my copy of VeraCrypt that are described in their help documentation, but I suspect they are disabled in the Linux version.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using TrueCrypt, you know, except that it's no longer supported.

Comment: @harrymc Has support for this been dropped, or was it always only available in Windows? The Changelog doesn't state anything.

Comment: @mat: TrueCrypt support and development have been stopped - the developers just walked away. Although its last version still works as well as it always did, it's recommended to use instead VeraCrypt.

Answer (score 6):

One option would be to set the the SUID bit on veracrypt. This would make sure it took on root privileges whenever run.

```bsh
# chmod u+s /usr/bin/veracrypt
```

Generally, however, I try to avoid the SUID or SGID bits, as they allow any user with permission to execute the binary to use it at elevated privileges.

**A better option:**

Another option you have if you've got `sudo` is to create a group with password-free sudo privileges for veracrypt.

*This is definitely a still a little less secure than always requiring a password, as is always the case when creating sudo rules like this.* ***Make sure you read this carefully and understand what it entails to ensure you do not create a security risk!***

---

Before you begin, you want to ensure that the `/usr/bin/veracrypt` binary is **not** writable by *group* or *other*.

Confirm that it is not writable by another other than the owner:

```bsh
$ ls -lha /usr/bin/veracrypt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7.1M Sep 11  2019 /usr/bin/veracrypt
```

First, create a new group:

```bsh
# groupadd veracrypt_group
```

Next, add your user(s) to the group:

```bsh
# usermod -aG veracrypt_group your_user
```

Now you now use `visudo` to create a new sudo rule:

```bsh
# visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/veracrypt
```

This one will allow the `veracrypt_group` to run `/usr/bin/veracrypt` without a password.

> %veracrypt_group ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/veracrypt

Comment: Thanks! To completely get rid of a password prompt I needed to add `mount` and `uptime` to the sudo rule: `%veracrypt_group ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/veracrypt, /usr/bin/mount, /usr/bin/uptime`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in Linux Mint when my veracrypt container was in a directory not owned by the user opening the container. Even though the user could write to that directory (and owned the container file). Moving it to a folder that the user owns stopped veracrypt from prompting for an admin password.